# SQLite Database to listView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I'm trying to get data from column `ITEMS` in my Database to appear in the `Items` listView when you click the `add` button. At the moment when you click the `add` button it just saves a item in a column of the database. I would appreciate an answer!

The main Java class (**New_Recipe**)

```
public class New_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

Button add,done,display;
EditText Recipe_Name,Recipe_Item,Recipe_Steps;
String search;
WebView webView;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
ListView Items;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new__recipe);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    setTitle("New Recipe");
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Recipe_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Recipe_Item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Recipe_Steps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    AddData();
    viewAll();

}

public void AddData() {
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         boolean inserted = databaseHelper.insertData1(Recipe_Name.getText().toString(),
                   Recipe_Steps.getText().toString());
            if (inserted == true)
                Log.d("Database", "Data successfully inserted!");
            else Log.d("Database","Data did not insert!");
        }
    });
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean inserted = databaseHelper.insertData2(Recipe_Item.getText().toString());
            if (inserted == true)
                Log.d("Database", "Data successfully inserted!");
         else Log.d("Database","Data did not insert!");
    }
    });
}
public void viewAll() {
    display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Cursor res = databaseHelper.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error","No Data found!");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                stringBuffer.append("Names :"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                stringBuffer.append("Items :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                stringBuffer.append("Steps :"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");

            }
            showMessage("Success!",stringBuffer.toString());
        }
    });
}
public void showMessage(String title,String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public void onSearch(View v) {
    search = "Recipes";
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q="+search);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new__recipe, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The Database Java class (**DatabaseHelper**)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Recipes.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = " Recipe_Table";
public static final String COL1 = "NAME";
public static final String COL2 = "ITEMS";
public static final String COL3 = "STEPS";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    Log.d("Database", "Database should be made!");
}


    @Override
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY,ITEMS TEXT,STEPS TEXT)");
        Log.d("Database", "Database should be made!, Again");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        Log.d("Database", "Table exists");
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData1(String name,String steps) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, name);
        contentValues.put(COL3, steps);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
         else
            return true;

    }
public boolean insertData2(String items) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(COL2, items);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
public Cursor getItemData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select"+COL2+"from"+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real Android way to do this would be to use a combination of `ContentProvider` and `CursorAdapter`.

Android already has a way to take a `Cursor` from a query and put the data in a `ListView`: The `CursorAdapter` class.  You just override `getView()` to create the item view for your list.

Here's what a custom `ContentProvider` will get you:  When you create a content provider URI and query it to get a `Cursor`, a `DataObserver` is set up, so that when you insert/delete/update data through the `ContentProvider` using that URI, the `Cursor` will get a notification that the data has changed and will re-query the data.  When that `Cursor` has been set on a `CursorAdapter`, the adapter will *also* see that the cursor data has changed and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

So the net result is that when you add a record, your `ListView` is *automatically* refreshed with current data.

For an introduction to Content Providers, refer to this article: [Content Providers | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: Good answer, I haven't tried this yet, but I will now :-)

Comment: `ContentProvider`s can be a little heavyweight for applications like this, but they have other nice features; for example, executing the queries off the UI thread. So I think it's worth looking into.

Comment: Executing queries from the UI thread, as opposed to creating an asynctask, or something similar? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an adapter that the list view can draw its data from. You will pass the data from your `getAllData()` call to the adapter, which the list view will then display.

If you haven't already, you can create a custom class which extends base adapter, implement the methods correctly, then all you have to worry about it the data.

First off, I always like to build a class that can store my data retrieved from the database. Something simple, like:

```
public class ItemObject {
    // Instance variables.
    private String mName, mItem, mStep;

    // Constructor.
    public ItemObject(String name, String item, String step) {
        mName = name;
        mItem = item;
        mStep = step;
    }

    // Create getters for each item.
    public String getName() { /*...*/ }
    public String getItem() { /*...*/ }
    public String getStep() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now you have an object that can store the items retrieved from the database table.  In your while loop after calling `getAllData()` you create your `ItemObject` there.

For example:

```
List<ItemObject> itemObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
while (res.moveToNext()) {
    // Extract values from the cursor.
    String name = res.getString(0);
    String item = res.getString(1);
    String step = res.getString(2);

    // Create the ItemObject and add it to the list.
    ItemObject item = new ItemObject(name, item, step);

    // Add it to the list.
    itemObjectList.add(item);
}
```

Now, you'll have a list of items you can pass directly to your adapter.

```
public class ItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Instance variables.
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ItemObject> mItemObjectList;

    // Constructor.
    public ItemsListAdapter(Context context, List<itemObjectList> itemObjectList) {
        mContext = context;
        mItemObjectList = itemObjectList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemObjectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItemObjectList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate your layout for each row here. I wont include list view 
        // optimization here, as you should look it up, its documentation
        // is readily available.
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        // Inflate the layout.
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_list_view_row_layout>, null);

        // Reference the views inside the layout that will display each value. (Name, Item, Step);
        TextView nameView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.<your_text_view_id>);
        // Do this for each view.

        // Now retrieve your data from the array list.
        ItemObject item = (ItemObject) getItem(position);

        // Now you have your item and the 3 values associated with it.
        // Set the values in the UI.
        nameView.setText(item.getName());

        // Return the view.
        return layout;
    }

    // Use this method to modify the data in the list view.
    // It's an ArrayList so simply add or remove elements, clear it, etc.
    public List<ItemObject> getAdapterList() {
        return mItemObjectList;
    }
}
```

To update the items in the list view, call `getAdapterList()` and modify the items in the `ArrayList` that is returned.  After modification, you must invalidate the list by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter itself.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for a late response. Now i'm getting an error in my logcat saying `E/ArrayAdapter﹕ You must supply a resource ID for a TextView`  I'm not quite sure why i'm using a text view in the first place, I thought I supposed to be working with a listView... :p